# Use two different numberings for footnotes in reledpar

Tags: numbering, footnotes, reledpar, bigfoot

The package [`reledpar`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledpar) already specifies two types of footnotes, `\footnoteA` and `\footnoteB`, but they use the same numbering system (arabic by default: 1, 2, 3, ...).

Is it possible to specify a custom numbering system for each of them? For example, roman (i, ii, iii, ...) or alphabetical (a, b, c, ...). If yes, how?

The package [`bigfoot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot), which easily allows this, can not be used here, because the definitions of `\footnoteA` and `\footnoteB` by `reledpar` and by `bigfoot` conflict.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\roman{footnoteA}}` or for alphabetical use `\alph`

Comment: @Mike Thank you! It works. If you want, you can write it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For roman numerals use

`\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\roman{footnoteA}}`

and you could have alphabetical for `\footnoteB` with

`\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\alph{footnoteB}}`